# How to assert uniqueness of a huge collection of strings?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, unique, collision

Let's say I have an algorithm which takes an `unsigned 64-bit integer` as input, and yields a `string` as a result. The string's alphabet is limited to `[a-z, A-Z, 0-9]` and its' maximum length is 16. So that's [image: 62^{16}] or 47,672,401,706,823,533,450,263,330,816 possible results.

I would like to assert the uniqueness of the algorithm's output. Read: I want to verify there are no collisions.

Is there an easy/quick 'n dirty way to do this, without having to fall back to (e.g.) some kind of database?

[EDIT]
Some clarification: the concerns uttered in the comments are legit, but no worries, I wasn't really planning on iterating over all possible combinations, my lifespan will probably be sub-1 century ;) Nor did I write my own algorithm to generate unique ID's. I just saw [this](http://hashids.org/net/#collisions) and started wondering how one would go about asserting uniqueness for algorithms with very large result sets that can't be handled in-memory
[/EDIT]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this is not possible to do because you need one-one mapping from 1064 elements to 6216 elements. This is not possible.

Comment: Randomly map a few numbers, probe a `HashSet` to verify there are no collisions. The more you probe, the more confidence you can have that it's probably OK. Sample size is limited by storage, confidence by time. If you want to absolutely *prove* your mapping is an injection, you're going to have to be abstract about it, because there's no way to do anything "quick" with that many items (judged by a human lifespan).

Comment: To put this in perspective a bit: if you had a bunch of networked computers that, in total, could convert a million integers a second for you (assuming there's no issue of storage for the moment), you'd still be waiting for over 500 centuries for confirmation that they're all unique. You know what's simpler than that and still guaranteed to produce unique, at most 16 character strings for every 64-bit integer? `Long.ToString("x")`.

Comment: Why are you doing this? There are ways to generate unique IDs and algorithms that are tested for this purpose. Why reinvent the wheal? ` Guid.NewGuid()`  dose this already.

Comment: If you wanted to check there were **no** collisions by brute force you'd have to test all 2^64 possible inputs. Suppose you could evaluate a million per second... it would still take over 584,000 years! As others have said, it's better to pick an algorithm that cannot produce duplicates by design.

Comment: Your concerns are all legit; it seems my question was too broad and the numbers too large :) I added a small clarification to my post.

Comment: For the specific library you mention, since it allows both encoding and decoding, a pragmatic approach (if you don't trust it 100%) would be to always decode again (at least in a debug build) after encoding and check that you get the original numbers back. If the strings weren't unique then you'd sometimes get different numbers when decoding them.

Comment: When each value gives a distinct string, then you will get "only" 2^64 possible strings that you need to check for duplicates.

Comment: It is undecidable if, given a function f from int to int, whether f(0) = 0. So there's no "quick and easy" way in general to find an answer to your question. One needs to look at the actual function you have and see how to approach proving uniqueness.

Comment: @VincentVanDenBerghe: as your link explains, you go about this by reasoning. The author of the particular function in question asserts uniqueness by specific properties. Not coincidentally, they use the fact that the hexadecimal representation of an integer is unique, just as I did in my suggestion. Of course they don't have a *proof* the mapping is unique, but such a proof is presumably easily constructed. If uniqueness is an important property (as it is here) you would not establish it by testing, as this is far less convincing. And slow.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, It would take a very long time to compute every possible entries, but just for fun, here is a try:

```
var workspace = new DirectoryInfo("MyWorkspace");

if (workspace.Exists)
{
    workspace.Delete();
}

workspace.Create();

var limit = 23997907;
var buffer = new HashSet<string>();

ulong i = 0;
int j = 0;

var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

while (i <= ulong.MaxValue)
{
    var result = YourSuperAlgorythm(i);

    // Check the result with current results
    if (buffer.Contains(result))
    {
        throw new Exception("Failure !");
    }

    // Check the result with older results
    foreach (var file in workspace.GetFiles())
    {
        var content = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllText(file.FullName).Split(';'));

        if (content.Contains(result))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failure !");
        }
    }

    buffer[j] = result;

    i++;
    j++;

    if (j == arrayLimit)
    {
        stopWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Resetting. This loop takes " + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + "ms");

        j = 0;

        var file = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(workspace.FullName, file), String.Join(";", buffer));

        buffer = new HashSet<string>();

        stopWatch.Restart();
    }
}
```

You could probably optimize it but you won't have enought of a lifetime to check the results. For now, it did not even create a file to store the first set of entries :D. I will edit this post when one loop will be done!

**Your only option is to prove mathematically your algorithm. Good luck with that...**

**EDIT1:** for my test, I use this function:

```
private static string YourSuperAlgorythm(ulong i)
{
    return i.ToString("x");
}
```

**EDIT2:** One loop takes 1477221.4261ms (~25min). And then the `String.Join(";", buffer)` line failed (OutOfMemory). So `23997907` is not the max value for my try. It must be decreased!

Comment: My guess was wrong, I end up with a OutOfMemory with this increment: 23997907. Just start a new one with a stopwatch to count the looptime.